# How to import a csv file from the admin side in django without the foreignkey column

Tags: django, foreign-keys, admin, import-csv

For the moment I can import csv file using Django's import_export package. However I need to provide a csv with the id corresponding to my foreign key.

Here is my modele.py :

```
class Category(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Cause(models.Model):
    
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

And here is admin.py :

```
from import_export.admin import ImportExportModelAdmin

# Register your models here.

class CategoryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ("name", )


class CauseAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    list_display = ("name",)
    pass


admin.site.register(Category, CategoryAdmin)
admin.site.register(Cause, CauseAdmin)
```

If I want to import a csv containing the names of the causes I need to add a column with the id of the corresponding categories. However, I would like to be able to import a csv containing only the names of the causes and choose the category on the admin side.

For the moment this is what it looks like when I import a csv file:

[image]

I would like to know if it is possible using the import_export package that it looks more like this: (like when I add only one cause)

[image]

Instead of the "Name" there would be as in the first screenshot " File to import " and the category could be chosen directly from the admin side.

So I will have csv with "id, cause_name" columns instead of "id, cause_name, category_id".

Do you know if it is possible to do this by continuing to use the import_export package? Or do I have to forget this way of doing things? For the moment I still have nothing that answers my problem.
Thank you in advance.